# Move element to parent

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am new to XSLT, i want to move a element with all its child elements to the root as mentioned below:

Input XML

```
<a name = "test">
  <b name = "test1">
    <c name = "test2">
        <c1>Dummy</c1>
    </c>
 </b>
</a>
```

Expected:

```
<a name = "test">
  <b name = "test1">        
  </b>
  <c name = "test2">
    <c1>Dummy</c1>
  </c>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  (This is called push programming.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />


  <xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|b"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="b/c"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Don't do an apply template with c in it. Just get the attributes for b. The c node pushed from the a template gets handled by the identity. -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Identity template. -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It just outputs the root element. The contents are not copied.

Comment: So I've updated my answer to include the entire style sheet; that might help you.  Also, I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio and the provided style sheet will do what you are asking against the provided XML.  Are you running this style sheet against different XML?  It sounds like you may have a namespace issue.  But, I will need to know the details about your processor and version, XML and XSLT.